# Is there a way in Hibernate to set not-null to true on save but not delete in a mapping config?

Tags: hibernate, nullable

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="org.lexiclan.orm.dao">
 <class name="Address" table="ADDRESSES" lazy="false">
  <id name="addressId" column="ADDRESS_ID">
   <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="addressType" column="ADDRESS_TYPE_ID" not-null="true" class="AddressType" lazy="false" />
  <many-to-one name="contact" column="CONTACT_ID" not-null="true" class="Contact" lazy="false" />
  <property name="address1" column="ADDRESS_1" />
  <property name="address2" column="ADDRESS_2" />
  <property name="city" column="CITY" />
  <property name="stateProvince" column="STATE_PROVINCE" />
  <property name="zipPostalCode" column="ZIP_POSTAL_CODE" />
  <property name="countryRegion" column="COUNTRY_REGION" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In this example, an address requires both a contact and an address type relationship before you can use "Session.save()" (which is what I want), but when I want to use "Session.delete()" I have to also specify a contact and address type relationship because of the not-null. Is there a way to require those values on save, but not on update/delete operations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"not-null" is not a conditional constraint. Either your properties (`addressType` / `contact`) are **ALWAYS** required, in which case you specify them as `not-null="true"` or they are not.

"Sometimes" is the same as "not required". If you need to perform conditional validation (for example, during insert but not during update or based on some other entity state), you can either do so in your code prior to invoking session methods or you can write an [event listener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events) or an [interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors) to do it for you.

That said, **deletion** is a special case. `session.delete()` deletes **persisted** entity, which means it has **already** been validated and has its properties as not-null. If you want to delete by id (that is, you don't have the entity loaded in session), you can use `session.load()` to obtain its proxy:

```
Address toBeDeleted = (Address) session.load(Address.class, id);
session.delete(toBeDeleted);
```

Either way I'm not quite sure what you mean by "I have to also specify a contact and address type relationship because of the not-null" in case of deletion. You don't - they're already set; they were specified when entity was persisted.

Comment: When I said "I have to" I just meant that Hibernate requires that those members on the object be set when I call save() because the object hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: Are you talking about **deletion**? If so, you don't ever have to call `save()` - either you call `get()` / `delete()` or `load()` / `delete()`. Otherwise, (if you're not talking about deletion) I've addressed conditional state checks in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **not null** is a database constraint. Why don't you use a HQL statement like the one  below:

```
session.Delete("from Order o where o.Id = :Id", id, NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Int32);
```

That way you don't need the whole object to delete it from database.

Answer (score -10):

I did not find any way to do it.
Consider using another ORM.

Comment: The question is referencing Hibernate, but this problem is not strictly Hibernate problem, and as such changing the ORM would not help.